# How to explain overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

```
SeedRandom[0];
X = RandomInteger[{1, 5000}, {100000, 50}];
Y = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 100000];
```

For `net1` and `net2` errors are around 50% for train and validation. No questions. Garbage in, garbage out.

`net3` has error on train 24.2%. This is good. But why `EmbeddingLayer` improves the quality of model in compare to `net2`? How to achieve this error on validation? Right now error on validation is 50.4% and logloss is 1.41.

I have anonymized dataset. I don't know meaning of features. Data has type "Real" and there are a lot of duplicates. I found that I can get good result during training if replace data with integer indices (using `ArrayComponents`) and use `EmbeddingLayer`. But result on validation is bad. I decided to check this neural network architecture on random data. And it can overfit random data!

How to explain overfitting?

```
net1 = NetChain[
  {
   128,
   Ramp,
   128,
   2,
   SoftmaxLayer[]
   },
  "Input" -> 50,
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
  ]
```

[image]

```
NetTrain[
 net1,
 N@X[[;; 70000]] -> Y[[;; 70000]],
 All,
 ValidationSet -> X[[70001 ;;]] -> Y[[70001 ;;]],
 MaxTrainingRounds -> 10,
 TargetDevice -> "GPU"
 ]
```

[image]

```
net2 = NetChain[
  {
   ReshapeLayer[{50, 1}],
   LongShortTermMemoryLayer[128],
   SequenceLastLayer[],
   2,
   SoftmaxLayer[]
   },
  "Input" -> 50,
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
  ]
```

[image]

```
NetTrain[
 net2,
 N@X[[;; 70000]] -> Y[[;; 70000]],
 All,
 ValidationSet -> X[[70001 ;;]] -> Y[[70001 ;;]],
 MaxTrainingRounds -> 10,
 TargetDevice -> "GPU"
 ]
```

[image]

```
net3 = NetChain[
  {
   EmbeddingLayer[10, 5000],
   LongShortTermMemoryLayer[128],
   SequenceLastLayer[],
   DropoutLayer[.2],
   2,
   SoftmaxLayer[]
   },
  "Input" -> 50,
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
  ]
```

[image]

```
NetTrain[
 net3,
 X[[;; 70000]] -> Y[[;; 70000]],
 All,
 ValidationSet -> X[[70001 ;;]] -> Y[[70001 ;;]],
 MaxTrainingRounds -> 10,
 TargetDevice -> "GPU"
 ]
```

[image]